# "There is no registered handler for URL scheme com-google-gidconsent" error when singning in using GIDSignIn

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin

I have manually integrated the google sign in sdk (not with cocoapods) and it builds ok, but when I run the project I always get this errors, after signing in:

```
2015-09-07 15:44:14.071 Contacts++[82438:4826277] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme com-google-gidconsent-google
2015-09-07 15:44:14.071 Contacts++[82438:4826277] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme com-google-gidconsent-youtube
2015-09-07 15:44:14.072 Contacts++[82438:4826277] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme com-google-gidconsent
2015-09-07 15:44:14.072 Contacts++[82438:4826277] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.1
2015-09-07 15:44:14.072 Contacts++[82438:4826277] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme com.google.gppconsent.2.4.0
```

This is how I am using the sdk.

First I follow all the steps from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift .

Code:
AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {  
    // google
    // Initialize sign in
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "<client id>"
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

    return true
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

    if error == nil {
        let userID = user.userID
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken
        let name = user.profile.name
        let email = user.profile.email

        print(userID, idToken, name, email)
    } else {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

}
```

ViewController.swift

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // google plus
        //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

What can be the issue ? I am using SDK version 2.2.0

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There's no problem with your implementation. All those warnings mean is the apps which each URL scheme refer to are not installed on the device.

If you're testing on the simulator, you'll get those errors all the time. But, if you test on a device, you can verify the errors will be gone if you have the corresponding apps installed.

For example, if you have the Youtube app on your device, you won't see the line:

```
2015-09-07 15:44:14.071 Contacts++[82438:4826277] LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme com-google-gidconsent-youtube
```

Answer (score -2):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"]];
        exit(0);
})
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how this answers the question.